# How do I add custom template files?

Tags: 8, theming

Currently, I am using the following code.

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme_registry_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_theme_registry_alter(&$theme_registry) {
  // Defined path to current module.
  $is_admin = Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute();
  $node = \Drupal::routeMatch()->getParameter('node');
  if (isset($node)) {
    if ($node->getType() == 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE' && $is_admin == 0) {
      $module_path = drupal_get_path('module', 'reveal_js');
       $theme_registry['html']['path'] = $module_path . '/templates';
       $theme_registry['page']['path'] = $module_path . '/templates';
    }
  }
}
```

This works, but when going to another page, I have to rebuild cache in order for it to re-evaluate whether the node is 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE' or a different type.

Comment: you should define hook_theme and use node__MY_CONTENT_TYPE and use node as base hook for it and place your template in your module's templates directory. This approach of your is very bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like `hook_theme_registry_alter()` is only executed when the theme cache is rebuilt. This means that what you need to do is use one of the theme_suggestion_alter hooks, such as `hook_theme_suggestions_alter()` or `hook_theme_suggestions_node_alter()`. These get run for each page before it is cached, I believe, instead of only once on cache rebuild.

So, what you want to do in your module is create a theme implementation using `hook_theme()`. That would look something like this:

```
function MYMODULE_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'my_theme_implementation' => array(
      'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'reveal_js') . '/templates',
      'template' => 'my_theme_implementation',
    ),
  );
}
```

And then your `hook_theme_suggestions_node_alter()` would be something like

```
function MYMODULE_theme_suggestions_node_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  $is_admin = Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute();
  $node = $variables['elements']['#node']
  if ($node->getType() == 'MY_CONTENT_TYPE' && $is_admin == 0) {
    $suggestions[] = 'my_theme_implementation';
  }
}
```

Does that all make sense?

Answer (score 1):

Tried both solutions listed and only the first one, using `hook__theme_registry_alter` had the desired result that I was looking for, i.e., I wanted to create a template that would behave just like creating a template file in a theme would do, i.e., want it to be processed just like a page template.  You can see that with the working implementation you get the full set of preprocess functions.

```
    [page] => Array
    (
        [template] => page
        [path] => modules/futusign/templates
        [type] => base_theme_engine
        [theme path] => core/themes/bartik
        [render element] => page
        [preprocess functions] => Array
            (
                [0] => template_preprocess
                [1] => template_preprocess_page
                [2] => contextual_preprocess
                [3] => futusign_preprocess_page
            )

    )
```